# magento checkout success page not showing after order placing

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

Magento checkout success page not showing after order placing.it's redirecting to checkout/cart showing empty,but order is placed.

I checked ajax call response, it's showing as below

[image: console screenshot]

I am also hitting `checkout/onepage/success` direct from url after comment all code in `successAction()`, but it's still redirecting to `checkout/cart`

Please help me for above issue.

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Can you update the code here.. of successAction()

Comment: i have integrated onestepcheckout to my website, working perfect